# Why can't I install any OS on samsung

Tags: windows-8, installation, operating-systems

I have laptop call it

**SAMSUNG**

- *OS:* WINDOWS 8.1 UNILINGUE 6 BITS (6.3 VERSION 9600)
- *Model:* 300E5E/300E4E/300E5V/300E4V
- *BIOS:* P02RBE

i'm trying to install any OS on it  but no luck even i use usb stick with seven 7 bootable or linux

- Why can't I install any OS in samsung

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're experiencing? Besides, if you have **Windows 8.1 Single Language**, there might be some restrictions I'm not familiar with. Check with Samsung to see what restrictions exist.

Comment: Do you have Windows 8 recovery media? Can you access the UEFI settings? If you can, try disabling Secure Boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and unfortunately, it comes down to the manufacturer. It's up to the manufacturer to decide whether to lock it down or not. My mom's laptop runs on Windows 8 and the only option you have is to recover Windows 8.

I would suggest contacting Samsung with the details and asking them if there is a workaround. There probably is a key combination press or something to get to the administration interface.

Not sure if you have seen this video yet? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peEJwjJ_Uf8 Not sure if it's due to restriction or your boot material.